# JSignature - problems exporting to jpeg

Tags: javascript, php, jsignature

I have a div which I'm applying the jSignature plugin to with

```
var $sigdiv = $(".jsig")
$sigdiv.jSignature() // inits the jSignature widget.
```

I have a button to capture this to base64 then pass it to PHP to create the image on the server.

```
$sig=$("#signature");
alert($sig.jSignature("getData"));
```

getData returns base64 for a PNG but I need a jpeg and I can't get it to work.
Has anybody come across a workaround please.

Answer (score 0):

As of `jSignature v2 "2016-11-05T00:40"` I couldn't find a way to export JPEG data with [jSignature](https://github.com/willowsystems/jSignature) without modifying the component code.

By applying this modification `jSignature('getData')` method with default export option will always export JPEG instead of PNG.

Alternatively you can enchance the `exportplugins` class in component code and add more export options to it.

**Solution:**

in jSignature.js or jSignature.min.js search for

```
{return this.toDataURL()}
```

and change it to

```
{return this.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8)}
```

which `0.8` is the image quality and can be from `0.1` to `1.0`.

[HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) explains other available options.